# R function breakpoints finds more breaks than Fstats

Tags: r, structural-change

I am using the `strucchange` package to detect structural changes in my data. 
The plot of my Fstats shows several peaks, yet if I use `breakpoints` one additional breakpoint is found. My F statistic at that point suggested by `breakpoints` is even below the threshold. Why does it find more?

Answer (score 3):

The F-statistic compares the model before and after a single breakpoint:
it is only valid if there are two segments.

The following shows what happens on a simple example.

```
library(strucchange)
y <- c(rnorm(20), 2+rnorm(20), rnorm(10)) # 2 breakpoints
b <- breakpoints( y ~ 1 )
f <- Fstats( y ~ 1 )
plot(b)  # 2 breakpoints
plot(f)  # Only 1 F-statistic above the threshold
lines(b)
```

Comment: thanks, for the your. Though I seem to not get the point (yet). Your y has two breakpoints obviously. Even if the Fstats finds only one, there should be two segments split by one breakpoints. `breakfactor(f)` only finds 1 segment.  All you state is that there has to be a single breakpoint. To me the question is: Why is there just one of two bps identified by the ftest while breakpoints manages to identify both?

Comment: The algorithm is not the same: 
`Fstat` tries to find one break point (i.e., two segments).
`breakpoints` tries to find the optimal number of segments,
basically by trying all possible breakpoints 
(the manual page `?breakpoints` gives more details about the algorithm).
`plot(b)` shows how the number of is chosen
(the algorithm tries to minimize the BIC).
What you want is probably a plot similar to `plot(f)`,
but not limited to a single breakpoint: I am not sure there is one.
`breakfactor(f)` issues a warning: it should be `breakfactor(b)`, 
which returns the 3 segments.

Comment: Thanks vincent. That's what i was looking for. I think what really disturbed me, was the fact that breakpoints accepts Fstats objects instead of just formulae. I think accidentally doing this confused me (which even works as peaks are breaks too). Thanks for helpful explanation though!